# No audio device, no errors

Tags: windows-7, audio, dell-precision

I've got a Dell Precision Workstation T3500 which for some reason is not showing any audio devices.

Looking in device manager there are no errors or missing devices, and in the system section there is a "High Definition Audio Device" shown, but there is no sound/audio devices section.

Looking in the sounds section in control panel it lists "no audio devices".

The motherboard has all the appropriate sound connectors, there is even a front headphone socket on the case, I can find no reason why the machine should not show a sound device. Looking on the Dell site for this machines tag, it lists an audio device and drivers for it, but when trying to run that it says it cannot detect a device.

I have checked the BIOS and the on board sound device is enabled.

The OS is Windows 7 X64.

I've also tried using the displayport connector for audio, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ocassionally mi Win7-64Bit does the same thing, no audio device is shown, I have to disconnect the speakers and connect them again and everything works fine then.

I haven't find a repeatable cause for this behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately disconnecting speakers (or headphones in this case) makes no difference, it is not detecting a sound device exists at all.